# Bulk resize conditionally with ImageMagick in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, imagemagick

I am trying to write a script to recursively iterate images and downsize them based on their aspect ratio.

If the image is in portrait orientation, it is downscaled to be 1200px wide at max.
(e.g., a file with a size of `2400x3840`, named `vertical.png`, should be downscaled to `1200x1920`).

If the image is in landscape orientation, it is downscaled to be 1920px tall at max.
(e.g., a file with a size of `4800x3840`, named `horizontal.png`, should be downscaled to `2400x1920`).

I have close to no knowledge on either batch or imagemagick so I have pieced together the following script:

```
FOR /R %%F IN (*.jpg, *.png) DO (
  SET R=magick identify -format "%[fx:w/h]" "%%F"

  echo %R%

  IF %%R LSS 1 (
    magick mogrify -resize 1200x^> "%%F"
  ) ELSE (
    magick mogrify -resize x1920^> "%%F"
  )
)
```

It works for most of it, except for the ratio calculation.

Running `magick identify -format "%[fx:w/h]" "C:\Users\Txus\Desktop\vertical.png"` directly on the terminal outputs `0.625`.

However, when the script runs the value outputted by `echo %R%` is the command itself, instead of the value it should be returning:
`magick identify -format "%[fx:w/h]" "C:\Users\Txus\Desktop\vertical.png"`.

How can i get this working?

---

***Update:***
I have tried the suggested changes.
(I will still keep the `magick` shorthand in the post for simplicity).
The he updated script looks like this:

```
FOR /R %%F IN (*.jpg, *.png) DO (
  SET R=magick identify -format "%[fx:w<h?1:-1]" "%%F"

  echo %R%

  IF %%R LSS 1 (
    magick mogrify -resize 1200x^> "%%F"
  ) ELSE (
    magick mogrify -resize x1920^> "%%F"
  )
)
```

However, the R variable still does not compute the command and just stores it as text. While running the lines directly on the terminal works:

```
magick identify -format "%[fx:w<h?1:-1]" "vertical.png"
1
magick identify -format "%[fx:w<h?1:-1]" "horizontal.png"
-1
```

The output of running the script is:

```
resizeManga.bat  
magick identify -format "w<h?1:-1]" "C:\Users\Txus\Desktop\vertical.png"  
magick identify -format "w<h?1:-1]" "C:\Users\Txus\Desktop\vertical.png"
```

(also note that the value contains `vertical.png` for both items, instead of one of them being `horizontal.png`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected: This Windows BAT script should read through all the JPG and PNG files in the directory, and... If the image is portrait orientation and more than 1200 wide, it will resize it to 1200 wide. If it's landscape and more than 1920 high, it will resize it to 1920 high. Otherwise it doesn't resize the input.

```
@echo off

for /R %%I in ( *.jpg *.png ) do (
   magick "%%I" -resize "%%[fx:floor(h/w)?1200:w/h*1920]x>" "%%I" )

exit /b
```

The "/R" switch on the "for" command makes it recurse through the folders.

The output overwrites the input file of the same name.